# Smallest element in a binary heap?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

Why does finding the smallest event in a binary heap take O(log V) time? (where V is the number of elements)

The Quicksort divide and conquer algorithm takes O(V) time to find the smallest element. Since finding the smallest element in a binary heap is almost identical to Quicksort (both divide the size of the problem by 2 at each step, and the number of problems stay the same) why do they have different times?

**Why does finding the smallest element using Quicksort and finding the smallest element in a binary heap take different amounts of time?**

Comment: Revise your assumptions. Quicksort does not find the smallest element (instead, it sorts, which is a larger and quite different problem) and does not run in O(V) (in the worst case, which I assume since you did not get more specific). A binary heap gives you the smallest element in O(1), assuming you just retrieve it and don't remove it (which entails reordering to maintain the heap property, and it's that step which takes O(log V) time).

Comment: @delnan

1) How would the binary heap take O(n)? Wouldn't it need to find the element first? A binary heap isn't sorted - the parents are simply larger than the children.

2)Wouldn't sorting a set of numbers allows finding the smallest element in O(1) time? Since if a set is sorted, the smallest number is simply the last number

Comment: (1) I am assuming a min-heap, which is just as common, and way more efficient for this use case. The only difference is that the *smaller* elements are put on top (i.e. you swap > for <). (2) Yes, you can sort to get the minimum easily, but that isn't Quicksort (instead, it's a distinct algorithm that happens to utilize any sorting algorithm), and it still isn't O(V) *worst case*. Even when you hit the O(V) average/best case, you can find the min. way simpler (and with a way lower constant) in O(V) via `minx = xs[0]; for x in xs: minx = min(minx, x)`.

Answer (score 2):

Any min-heap (not necessarily binary) will give you the smallest element in `O(1)` time. This is because the smallest element is the root of the heap (satisfying the heap property).

I think the problem here is that you're confusing your data structures. In an **unsorted list** any algorithm will take at least `O(N)` time, where N is the number of elements.

If your data is already stored in a **heap** structure, then the minimum can be extracted in `O(1)` time. However it's worth noting that constructing the heap in the first place from an unsorted list will take `O(N)` time.

If you have a **sorted list**, then you can use binary search to find the minimum in `O(log N)` time. But again, sorting takes at least `O(N)`.

Comment: How would constructing a binary heap from an unsorted list take O(n)? Doesn't it take atleast O( n log n) time to sort a set of numbers with an algorithm such as Mergesort?

Comment: You're talking about two different things again. Constructing a binary heap is not the same thing as sorting. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Building_a_heap for the algorithm.

Comment: If the list is sorted, shouldn't getting the minimum be O(1) because it's simply the first (or last, depending on sort order) item?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to find the smallest element in a max heap, it will take O(V) time, and not O(log V) time, as you said. The problem is not divided in two halves at each step. Because, once you establish it is smaller than the root, the minimum element could be in any of the 2 sub tress. Hence, you need to traverse both sub trees to find the min element.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about the pivot-based selection algorithm that is really similar to quicksort, finding the min in both cases is fundamentally different. What I mean is that the quick-sort-based selection algorithm picks a pivot and partitions your elements and then you know which of the remaining segments the number you are looking for is in. A binary heap does not have an analogous property. The special property of the heap is that every node is smaller than it's parent (assuming we are talking about a max-heap). Like one of the other answers said, this restricts the number of viable candidates of O(log(V)) as that is how many leaves you can have in a binary heap. However, (as far as I know) you must either maintain a list of leaves, or your heap must be represented as an array in order for you to get a time-complexity benefit from this. If your heap is stored as a set of linked nodes that just has a pointer to the first element, in the worst case, you have to search all of its children to find the minimum if only because that's the only way you can even see the leaves. I know this question has a lot of answers already, and most of them are mostly right, but I hope this clarifies some things.

Also, just to be clear, the actual quick-sort sorting algorithm (if randomized) runs in amortized O(nlogn) time. And finding the least element in a sorted array is O(1).